# Why href link inside an Iframe is not working on ios device?

Tags: php

I am developing a web app for an iframe, but in the iframe when clicking on the hyperlink (href) it shows a blank page on ios device. Bytheway it is working on all other devices except iPhone

I tried to find out everything on the internet, there is no relevant answer to my problem

When I click on the href link it should redirect another webpage of the same domain

Comment: What does your code look like? Where does the link point? What is "all other devices"?

Answer (score -1):

Try this way

```html
<html>
<style>
body 
 {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}
 </style>
 
 <body>
<center><iframe src="http://example.com" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe></center>
</body>
</html>
```

href is for links not for iframes, also make sure your links are not using target="_blank", your question could be more clear if you post the code, so we could understand what you really need